# In weld how do I initialize an object before its injected

Tags: java, dependency-injection, initialization, weld

I have a simple POJO class that I inject in to many places. There is no explicit Producer for it. I just do `@Inject POJO mypojo` and it works great.

Now my problem is that I want to initialize the POJO object(which involves reading from a datasource) before its injected to other places. The datasource itself is injected as `@Resource(name = "jdbc/xx") DataSource ds;` within the POJO.
Now in the constructor of my POJO, the `ds` is null, its only injected after the constructor is complete.

Is there a hook I can get after creating of the object and before injection so I can initialize my object before injection?

Comment: Thats what @PostConstruct is supposed to be for. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @Perception Thanks, i didnt knew about that. Can you please add you comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No problem @SurajChandran, answer posted and good luck with the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `@PostConstruct` annotation is for. It is called after your bean is constructed by the CDI container, but before it is actually placed into service. Example:

```
public class POJO {
    public Pojo() {
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void initialize() {
        // initialization code here
    }
}
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html